# Error: Stack around the variable "m" is corrupted

Tags: c, variables

Im trying to make a program which says how many times a specific digit appears on a 100 numbers sequence.
Meanwhile I got this error and I can´t understand what is the solution to this. I´d appreciate if you could get me some tip or the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int i, m, digit, val[99], count=0;

printf("Enter a number:");
scanf("%d", &val[0]);
while (val[0] < 0) {
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &val[0]);
}

for (i=1;i<101;i++) {
    val[i]=val[0]++;
    printf("%d\n", val[i]);
}

printf("Enter a digit:");
scanf("%d", &m);
while (m<0||m>9) {
    printf("Enter a digit:");
    scanf("%d", &m);
}

do {
    digit=val[i]%10;
    val[i]=val[i]/10;
    if (digit==m) {
        count++;
    }
}while (val[i]>0);

printf("The digit %d is printed %d times in this sequence.", m, count);

}
```

Comment: What do you thinkk will happen when you access `val[100]` when you have declared the size to be 99?

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop you step outside of the array *val* of which the last index is 98. Instead of hard-coding the length of the array in several places it is more convenient to use a length macro, like this:

```
#define LEN(anArray) (sizeof (anArray) / sizeof (anArray)[0])
...
for (i = 1; i < LEN(val); i++) {
...
```

Also, in the do-while loop the index *i* is outside of the array bounds of *val*. You also need to check the return value of *scanf* to make sure the input is valid. The last *printf* statement also needs a trailing newline.

Edit: Note that *LEN* only handles "real" arrays; arrays passed to  functions are received as pointers.

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed but that's due to arr being a pointer rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated only `int /* ... */ val[99]` (only `val[0]` to `val[98]` are available) and accessed upto `val[100]` because the loop condition is `i<101`.

This will lead to dangerous out-of-range write (*undefined behaior*).

Allocate enough elements like `int /* ... */ val[101]` or fix the loop condition not to cause out-of-range access.

Also you didn't set value of `i` after the `for (i=1;i<101;i++)` loop, so value of uninitialized element will be used in the `do ... while` loop. Values of uninitialized elements of non-static local variables are indeterminate and using the value invokes *undefned behavior*.
Set `i` to proper value before the loop or change the indice `i` to proper thing.